# Change order of rows in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this (here is a simplified version):

```
create table t(
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  room varchar(10),
  kind char(1),
  value double
  );

insert into t(room,kind,value) values
  ('009','T',23),
  ('009','H',35),
  ('All','P',740),
  ('008','T',22),
  ('008','H',35),
  ('106','T',22),
  ('106','H',38),
  ('006','H',40),
  ('006','T',25),
  ('All','P',740);
```

When I select `room` and `kind`, it gives me rows in the order of appearance:

```
select distinct room, kind from t;

| room | kind |
|------|------|
|  009 |    T |
|  009 |    H |
|  All |    P |
|  008 |    T |
|  008 |    H |
|  106 |    T |
|  106 |    H |
|  006 |    H |
|  006 |    T |
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
|  room  | kind |
|--------|------|
|  room1 |    T |
|  room1 |    H |
|  room2 |    T |
|  room2 |    H |
................
|  All   |    P | <-- this should be the last row
```

i.e. every room should have a kind 'T' then 'H', and the last row should have room='All'. Is it possible to do it without making complicated query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just looking for `order by`:

```
select distinct room, kind
from t
order by (room = 'All') asc,  -- put 'All' last
         room, kind desc;
```

Why does this work?  MySQL treats a boolean expression (such as `(room = 'All')`) as a number, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  Hence, the "true" values are sorted after the "false" values.

Note:  Your data doesn't seem to have rows with repeated values of `room`/`kind`.  If you have no duplicates, then use `select` rather than `select distinct`.

Comment: @MichaelO. . . . Just use `kind desc` instead of `kind`.

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
select distinct kind,room  from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

every string which starts with digit , for example '01', '54154A' always smaller than string which start with 'A' character, for example 'ALL'

try it

```
select distinct room, kind from t order by room
```